# Python multithreading and HTTP requests

Tags: python, multithreading, http

I am working on a Python backend web server that grabs realtime data from a paid 3rd party API.
I need to query this API very fast (about 150 queries per 10 seconds). Therefore, I created a small proof of concept that spawns 200 threads and writes urls to a queue. The threads then read from the url from the queue and send the HTTP request. The 3rd party API returns a value called delay, which is how long it took their server to process the request.
Here is the POC code that just downloads all the urls (not repeatedly).

```
_http_pool = urllib3.PoolManager()

def getPooledResponse(url):
    return _http_pool.request("GET", url, timeout=30)

class POC:
    _worker_threads = []
    WORKER_THREAD_COUNT = 200
    q = Queue.Queue()

    @staticmethod
    def worker():
        while True:
            url = POC.q.get()
            t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
            r = getPooledResponse(item)
            print "thread %s took %d seconds to process the url (service delay %d)" % (threading.currentThread().ident, (datetime.datetime.now() - t0).seconds, getDelayFromResponse(r))
            POC.q.task_done()

    @staticmethod
    def run():
          # start the threads if we have less than the desired amount
          if len(POC._worker_threads) < POC.WORKER_THREAD_COUNT:
              for i in range(POC.WORKER_THREAD_COUNT - len(POC._worker_threads)):
                  t = threading.Thread(target=POC.worker)
                  t.daemon = True
                  t.start()
                  POC._worker_threads.append(t)

          # put the urls in the queue
          for url in urls:
              POC.q.put(url)
              # sleep for just a bit so that the requests don't get sent out together (this is a limitation of the API I am using)
              time.sleep(0.3)   
POC.run()
```

When I run this, the first few results are returned with a reasonable delay:

```
thread 140544300453053 took 2 seconds to process the url (service delay 1.782)
```

However, after about 10-20 seconds I get these kinds of things:

```
thread 140548049958656 took 23 seconds to process the url (service delay 1.754)
```

In other words, even though the server returns with a small delay, my threads take longer to complete...

How do I test to see where the other 21 running seconds are spent?

Thanks!

Comment: [have you checked out the Python GIL issues related to multiple threads?](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: thanks. what exactly do I need to do here? is there any way to avoid these issues?

Comment: well i would definitely do what Ali recommended, which is to get a profiler for your code.  Though it may be that you are running into GIL issues, in that case it wont matter what you do, the GIL may be what is causing the slowdown as it essentially causes all of your threads to run in serial.  You would need to use separate processes - not threads - to beat the GIL issues.  Or find a way to make the code threadsafe, but i'm not fluent enough in multi-threaded/processed python coding to direct you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) on the code.